# How To Set Class Variables By Key

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm updating one of my models and I'm sending in a dictionary of attributes with their updated values.  Is there an easy way to access my instance variables by their name?

e.g.

```
[myObject setValueByVariableName:@"varName" value:@"new_value"];
```

**Update**

I think I might have answered my own question ... testing it with

```
[myObject setValue:(id)val forKey:(NSString*)key];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[myObject setValue:@"some_value" forKey:@"some_instance_variable"];
```

See the Key-Value Coding (KVC) documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: And for the case where you have a dictionary mapping attributes to values, you can use `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`, which is also part of KVC.